# Is there a difference between List<String> A = new ArrayList<String> ( ) and ArrayList<String> A = new ArrayList<String>()?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

```
String[] somestringarray = { "a","b","c"};
```

Also,

```
List<String> A = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(somestringarray));
```

is `Arrays.asList()` a collection? And the statement is initializing a list of the size of `somestringarray`?

Why can't I just have `somestringarray`? what is the point of declaring a list of strings, what is wrong having just `somestringarray`?

Comment: ArrayList does not implement the Array interface, therefore you cannot assign an ArrayList reference value to an Array reference variable.

Comment: Also, there is no `Array` interface, in Java. An `ArrayList` is a kind of a `List`. `Arrays.asList()` *returns* a collection.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are extremely bare-bones, fundamental components of the Java language, without any of the nice features provided by the collections framework: no `contains`, fixed-size, unavoidably mutable, and so on.

`Arrays.asList` returns a special `List` implementation that is *just* a wrapper around the array passed to it: it supports `set`, `contains`, iteration, and all of that, though it doesn't support `add` or `remove`.  It can be passed to many utilities that expect a `Collection`, however, because `Arrays.asList` *does* return a `List`, which is always a `Collection`.

The statement

```
List<String> A = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(somestringarray));
```

is, first, wrapping your array as a `List`, but a limited implementation that does not support resizing.  (Also, the `List` reflects changes you make to `somestringarray`, and changes to the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` would actually change the backing array as well.)  **Then**, it copies that into an `ArrayList`, which is a full-featured `List` implementation supporting resizing, etc., and since it makes a copy it is now independent of the original array.

Comment: And, worst of all, arrays are covariant, breaking type safety.

Comment: @DavidConrad You mean compilation-time type safety, since at runtime arrays will check if element which we try to put in array is of the right type. It is true that we can use `Object[]` reference to hold `String[]` array, but if we will try to place in such array for instance Integer we will be stopped with little help of `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, compilation-time type safety.

Comment: What about List<String> A = new ArrayList<String> ( ) and Array<String> A = new ArrayList<String>(), there is not difference between those two statements right?

Comment: @Lydia: there is no Array class, so the difference is that the second version wouldn't make any sense or compile.

Comment: @louisWasserman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEqvmsqjpT0, in this video Derek Banas used ArrayList. Never mind, I spelt it wrong :p. What I meant is ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 1):

Java Arrays are not dynamic data structures; once intialized they can't be resized. Whereas `List` is a `Collection` interface, and `ArrayList` is a `List` backed by an array.

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
al.add("c");
```

With arrays you'd need

```
String[] arr = {"a","b"};
// can't add "c" now.
```

to add "c" when you initialize `arr` without copying it into a new array,

```
String[] t = new String[arr.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, t, 0, arr.length);
t[t.length - 1] = "c";
arr = t;
```